# Какие форматы поддерживает XmlDataProvider?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Подскажите, можно ли работать с xhtml/html через XmlDataProvider или же он работает исключительно с .xml?

Например я хочу выдрать с сайта какой-то набор значений и вывести их в список.
Делаю так, но результата нет:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider Source="https://vk.com/" x:Key="vk"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource vk}}">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=//div/text()}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Для получения информации с сайта, у которого есть официальное API (а у vk есть API), нужно пользоваться официальным API. Иначе ожидайте бана на сайте, который вы парсите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XmlDataProvider действительно работает только с XML. Вам нужна библиотека парсера, рекомендую [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp)